# C++ Clang emit warning about unused template variable

Tags: c++, c++17, clang++

#### C++ Clang emit warning about unused template variable

Considering an unused template variable definition, such as this one :

```cpp
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_complete : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct is_complete<T, std::void_t<decltype(sizeof(T))>>
    : std::true_type {};
template <typename T>
constexpr static inline auto is_complete_v = is_complete<T>::value;
```

Here, Clang emit a warning about unused `is_complete_v` variable, which seems wrong to me.
Why would such variable symbol be instanciated at all, if unused ? Perhaps I'm missing a point.

```
warning: unused variable 'is_complete_v' [-Wunused-const-variable]
    static inline constexpr auto is_complete_v = is_complete_v<T>::value;
```

The case is, other compiliers like GCC does not emit any warning.
Which IMOO makes sens, as the symbol is not resolved.

I could fix up all the codebases I'm working with using either :

```cpp
template <typename T>
#if __clang__
[[maybe_unused]]
#endif
constexpr static inline auto is_complete_v = is_complete<T>::value;
```

Or by disabling `-Wunused-const-variable`,

But I wonder if :

- Is there a cleaner way to achieve this ?
- Is this a normal behavior ?

Comment: Can you comment on why `is_complete_v` is `static`? Clang is likely complaining because it recognizes that it is impossible for any instance of that symbol to be used outside of the current translation unit, even if no instances have been made.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for pin-pointing this ! This definitely is a remainder from a C++ standard migration script, that did not trigger any error since. In fact, `-Wall` was disabled when using Clang (and Clang-CL /W4 did not trigger it).

Comment: the variable is indeed not used

Comment: @BЈовић I disagree. To me, this template variable symbol is not instanciated, thus simply does not exists from a symbols generation perspective. Thus, it should not generate a warning.
In opposition, I'd agree for instance if you'd tell me `is_complete_v<int>` is unused, as this is a well-defined symbol.

Comment: @Guss: How could `is_complete_v<int>` be unused?  You’d have to use it to have it be instantiated (or else explicitly instantiate or specialize it).  Clang is trying to let you know that you have dead code; why not just **remove** it?

Comment: @Guss remove `static` and the warning will go away. it is not well defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The heuristics for the Clang "unused" class of diagnostics don't appear to inspect each instantiation at all, but rather the uninstantiated template itself.

I've experienced similar issues myself, specifically when relying on constructors within template functions to produce side effects (for RAII, etc.). When Clang needs to know the template parameter passed in order to determine the constructor that was used, it naively treats the constructor as pure and marks the constructed variable unused (`Wunused-variable`), but if the constructor can be determined without instantiating the template, then it will not mark the variable unused because it can determine that the constructor produces an observable side-effect.

In your case, since it's likely that your template is in a header file anyway, it makes no difference whether it's marked `static` or not. Use the [type traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) library "possible implementations" as a guide and avoid marking these template values as `static` in order to avoid the diagnostic.

Comment: Good explanation about internal Clang behavior, thx. I accepted this answer.