# Why does clang seem to inconsistently issue -Wpessimizing-move

Tags: c++, clang++

Why does clang issue a `-Wpessimizing-move` for the first function, but not the second function?

Is it because the template function 'may or may not' be instantiated with a 'true/false'?  If that is the case, why is the warning not issued when the template is instantiated with `true`?

Compiling with `-Wall` or `-Wpessimizing-move`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
auto internal_constexpr()  {
    constexpr bool foo = true;
    if constexpr(foo){
        std::vector<int> a{1,3,3,4};
        return std::move(a);
    }else{
        return std::vector<int>{1,2,3,4};
    }
}

template<bool foo>
auto template_param()  {
    if constexpr(foo){
        std::vector<int> a{1,2,3,4};
        return std::move(a);
    }else{
        return std::vector<int>{1,2,3,4};
    }
}

int main(){
  auto a = template_param<true>();
  auto b = internal_constexpr();
  std::cout << a.size() << ", " << b.size();
}
```

Comment: Looking at the uninstantiated template function, the compiler doesn't have enough information to tell whether there will be a pessimizing move or not. It may be that the warning follows similar heuristics as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67128620), though I'd need to experiment more with this warning to be sure.

Comment: clang12 doesn't issue any warnings. https://godbolt.org/z/z86chT8oW

Comment: @david, sorry it needs `-Wall`.

Comment: https://bugs.llvm.org/ ?

Comment: I ran the code through [cppinsights](https://cppinsights.io/) and copied the result back into [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/6rPvPsYEc), expecting _both_ functions to trigger the warning - but instead, now _none_ of them does. Hmm ...

Comment: If you change `auto` to `std::vector<int>` you'll get the warning for both the function and the function template.

Comment: Well they definitely are both getting copied... https://godbolt.org/z/sbbqsdKM7

Comment: @DavidBien if you add a move constructor to the subclass it will state that they are being moved.  But this brings up a much more surprising result: taking off the `std::move`'s with the 'printing move constructor' shows that the `internal_contexpr` is eliding, but the template one is not.

Comment: Well this you mean: https://godbolt.org/z/74shM77qb That just brings up another question: I should have injected the vector's move constructor by using vector's constructors with "using vector< T >::vector;" - so why did it preferentially choose my copy constructor over my injected vector constructors which presumably include vector's move constructor?

Comment: Then there's this: https://godbolt.org/z/KhKerEWqj - using the default move constructor - which is vector's move constructor - since we aren't printing "copied."

Comment: That's the most significant thing I've learned from this thread: If you declare a copy constructor, even having injected the base class's constructors - which may include a standard move constructor ( like vector does ), then you reset the idea of what happens to that object when attempted to be moved - it will be copied constructed instead.

Comment: @Zac I don't know exactly what you are saying. Example please?